# Python Underscore Inside List

Tags: python, list, numpy, jupyter-notebook, slice

I realize that underscores are used for a number of cases, such as throwaway variables in python.

I recently came across the following example:

```
a = [1, 2, 5, 3]
a[_]
```

Now the second line returns a 2. What is going on here?
EDIT:

In Jupyter Notebook, this following example should work:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]

for _ in range(2):
    print(a[_])

a[_]
```

This outputs:

```
1
2
2
```

But surely the _ in the a[_] should be out of scope here?

Comment: please show some code above. other way you should get an error `NameError: name '_' is not defined`

Comment: @BearBrown not true, in the IPython shell using `_` would be valid, but regardless we need to see some code

Comment: @gold_cy ipython run some magic so it is not the same as python.

Comment: @BearBrown OP never specified _where_ he was running this, IPython is still Python

Comment: Added more details to my original post

Comment: Your first example does not run *on its own*. `_` is a simple variable, just like `i` or `my_special_variable_name`. It only happened to be `1` because of some code you ran earlier. Example #2 behaves perfectly normal.

Comment: Always use `range(len(a))` instead of hardwiring the length of the list!

Comment: This use of underscore is typical of Python interactive environments such as `ipython/jupyter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many cases, and I presume this case as well, the `_` represents the last value created, regardless of the variable type. For example, in trying to replicate this in Ipython, I created the list `a` and then attempted to reference one of the elements via the `_`. Since my last variable created was a list, this failed:

```
In [99]: a = [1, 2, 3, 4]                                                                                                                                                                                               

In [100]: a[_]                                                                                                                                                                                                          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-100-81d8b9395518> in <module>
----> 1 a[_]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

In your `for` loop, you are presuming that the target variable is in scope for the entirety of the `for` loop and then goes out of scope. This is not the case. The last value of the target value in a for loop is not garbage collected OR deleted.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]

for _ in range(2):
    print(a[_])

a[_] 

1       # index 0, points at a value of one.
2       # index 1, points at a value of two.
2       # we have left the for loop, but the _ still points at the
        #     last value it was associated with, a 1 and thus 
        #     the list indexing expression retrieves a value of two.
```

This is an alternate example to show this phenomena at work:

```
In [109]: for word in ['alpha', 'beta', 'zeta']: 
     ...:     print(word) 
     ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                               
alpha
beta
zeta

In [110]: word         # let's examine word outside the for loop:                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[110]: 'zeta'
```